# How to get all fields in a form with maxlength attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `html5` to develop my views and came through a situation with `maxlength`, I have few fields in a form with `maxlength` attribute.

Actually `maxlength` is working fine in `desktop browsers` but not working in `android browsers` So I want to achieve that using some explicit `javascript` validation.

Instead of getting each and every element in form based on id like `document.getelementbyid('firstname').maxLength;`
I want to get all elements in a form with `maxlength` attribute.

So I need a generic solution for this...

Thanks !!

Actually I tried a solution as below:

```
$('input[maxlength]').on('keydown', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > $this[0].maxLength) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This is not working..

Comment: Your [proposed solution](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hsjkgtcm/) works fine, do you have a specific issue?

Comment: My solution is not working in android browser

Comment: Which specific Android browser? There's no reported issues with the `maxlength` attribute not working: https://caniuse.com/#search=maxlength

Comment: Chrome, it is allowing the to enter characters beyond the maxlength and then when the user tabs out it is truncating the value entered up to maxlength...
But my requirement is to not allow the user to enter characters beyond the maxlength

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jQuery filter method along with the hasAttribute function. This would filter the object to only items that have the attribute that you desire.

```
function filterByAttribute(dom, attr) {
  var answer = dom.filter(function(input){
    return (this).hasAttribute(attr);
  });
  return answer;
}

var objArray = filterByAttribute($('input'), 'maxlength');

objArray.on( ... <your code here> ... );
```

https://api.jquery.com/filter/

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-hasattribute/

Comment: objArray.on( ... <your code here> ... ); what does this your code mean,, what should be written here

Comment: does this mean as below
objArray.on('keydown', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'), 10)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

Comment: After reading the comments on the question, I think I misunderstood your question. I was thinking you were needing a better way to filter out the array to only objects that have the attribute 'maxlength'. By the comments, it looks like you need a better way to stop an input from accepting characters once the input hits maxlength. Is that more accurate?

Comment: @Meena, yes, my initial intent was for you to add the rest of your code as in your comment. Is it really your inner code that the question is asking about?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, my intent is to get all the input elements having maxlength attribute in a form.

Comment: Ok. Then the above should work. Although, so should your above code. How many dom objects are you getting versus what are expected?